# prove that $(S,\circ)$ is non-abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $(G,\circ)$ is an abelian group where we define the binary operation $\circ$ on $G$ by $x\circ y= x+y+xy$

where, $G=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}|q\neq-1\}.$

Comment: What are the elements of $G$? Integers?

Comment: Have you tried anything on this? It's an absolutely direct application of the axioms for a group, so it's difficult to help without knowing what's causing you trouble.

Comment: I know how to prove all property about abelian group but which i did not know under $\circ$ this operation this one is very difficult this i need help thanks

Comment: The title change in revision 4 makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [abelian group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) has five axioms, all of which need to be proved here.

1. Closure.
   Assume $x,y\in G$, now we need to prove that $x\circ y\in G$.  The tricky thing is to prove that $x+y+xy\neq -1$.  If we assume it does equal $-1$, a bit of algebra gets a contradiction.
2. Associativity
   $(x\circ y)\circ z$ needs to be equal to $x\circ (y \circ z)$.  This is a bit messy:
   $(x+y+xy)\circ z=x+y+xy + z + (x+y+xy)z$, while $x\circ (y+z+yz)=x+y+z+yz+x(y+z+yz)$.  A bit of algebra shows that both of these are equal to $x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+xyz$.
3. Identity
   You need a special element $e$ such that $x\circ e=x$ for all $x$.  It turns out $e=0$ works for this purpose, because $x \circ 0 = x + 0 + x0 = x$.
4. Inverse
   For each $x$, you need to find an $x^{-1}$ such that $x\circ x^{-1}=e$.  It turns out that $x^{-1}=\frac{-x}{1+x}$, which is well-defined because $x\neq -1$.  A bit of algebra shows that also $x^{-1}\neq -1$.
5. Commutativity
   This one is easy, because $x\circ y=x+y+xy=y+x+yx=y\circ x$.

Comment: thank you very much but about property one how i get conduction also property 4 how i can show that$ x^-1\neq-1 $ just these part i need explain thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Filling in @vadim123 proof of closure we assume that $x\circ y = -1$.  This means  that $x+y+xy = -1$ or rearranging $xy + x+y+1 = (x+1)(y+1) = 0$.  However, this is only possible if $x=-1$ or $y=-1$ contradicting the fact that the group $G$ excludes the element $-1$.

Comment: property 4 how i can show that $x^{-1}\neq -1$ just these part i need explain thank you very much

Comment: can you please explain property 4 how i can show that x−1≠−1

Comment: It's becoming clear that these are HW problems.  I think you should think about that on your own.

Comment: In property 4, suppose $x^{-1}=\frac{-x}{1+x}=-1$.  We multiply both sides by the nonzero $1+x$ to get $-x=-1-x$, which simplifies to $0=-1$, a contradiction.

Comment: thank you so much expert vadim123 thank you for helping me and give to me idea to solve thank you again

Comment: @leena, I sincerely hope that you are trying to learn from this solution, rather than copying it blindly and submitting it as your own.  My initial solution left small gaps for you to fill in; you asked for help even with these.